# Xamarin Forms: How to create a dynamic IMarkupExtension?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In my XAML, when I bind an element property to a property in my view model, under the covers it is using the BindingExtension class which looks like this:

```
public sealed class BindingExtension : IMarkupExtension<Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase>
```

If I create my own class which implements IMarkupExtension, I only need to define one method:

```
public Object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

But if my extension class realizes that the value it provided has now changed (like BindingExtension does), how does my class notify the XAML of this fact?

To give a concrete (though unrealistic) example, let's say I want to create an extension that returns the time.  Yes, I realize I can do this with the normal binding, this is just to explain the question:

```
public class TimeExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public Object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

How can I change this, so that as the time changes, my extension provides an updated time value to the outside world?

Comment: `BindingExtension` doesn't just provide a value and evaporate (I know WPF Binding returns a `BindingExpression` form ProvideValue; I can't find the Xamarin reference source but it'll be in that ballpark). It stays around listening to events from the source and/or target and updates the target and/or source properties. Your TimeExtension would want to sit around forever, updating the target property. But it might make more sense to write a TimeEmitterViewModel with a timer that updates a public `Time` INPC property, create one as a resource, and bind your view property to that.

Comment: I whipped up a quick example but it's WPF. I ran into one thing that seems to be different between the two: Do you know how to invoke into a UI thread in Xamarin, given a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want, but I'm not certain how to invoke into the UI thread in Xamarin, so that part may need some work.

(UPDATE: See below for my version of the solution OP came up with. It's better than what I had; I didn't think of implementing INPC on the markup extension itself, so I went off in the wrong direction).

The "magic" so to speak is in getting `IProvideValueTarget` so you have a target dependency property identifier and a reference to the actual dependency object that owns the target property. Once you've got that, the rest is trivial stuff: Make a timer, update the property without crashing. It would be preferable to update the target property via a binding, because then we wouldn't have to mess around with the dispatcher, but I guessed (wrongly, perhaps) that this approach would most minimize the exposure to Xamarin-specific stuff.

```
public class TimeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    System.Threading.Timer _timer = null;
    //DispatcherTimer _timer = null;

    public TimeExtension() { }
    public TimeExtension(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        Interval = interval;
    }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250);

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget provideValueTarget = 
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

        if (provideValueTarget.TargetObject is DependencyObject targetobj)
        if (provideValueTarget.TargetProperty is DependencyProperty targetProp)
        {
            System.Threading.TimerCallback tick 
                    = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //  This is what worked in WPF:
                    //(targetobj as Control).Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    //  I *think* this may work in Xamarin. Maybe. 
                    (targetobj as NSObject).InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        targetobj.SetValue(targetProp, DateTime.Now);
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _timer.Dispose();
                    _timer = null;
                }
            });

            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tick, null, 0, (int)Interval.TotalMilliseconds);
            //  WPF
            /*
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Interval = Interval;
            _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    targetobj.SetValue(targetProp, DateTime.Now);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    targetobj.SetValue(targetProp, ex.Message);
                    _timer.Stop();
                }
            };
            _timer.Start();
            */
        }

        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Here's my test XAML in WPF:

```
<Label 
    Content="{local:Time 00:00:00.100}" 
    ContentStringFormat="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffff" 
    />
```

---

### OP's Approach

Tested with WPF

```
public class TimeExtension : MarkupExtension, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    System.Threading.Timer _timer = null;

    public TimeExtension() { }
    public TimeExtension(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        Interval = interval;
    }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250);


    #region CurrentTime Property
    private DateTime _currentTime = default(DateTime);
    public DateTime CurrentTime
    {
        get { return _currentTime; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentTime)
            {
                _currentTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion CurrentTime Property


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget provideValueTarget =
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

        if (provideValueTarget.TargetObject is DependencyObject targetobj)
        {
            if (provideValueTarget.TargetProperty is DependencyProperty targetProp)
            {
                System.Threading.TimerCallback tick
                    = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(o =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _timer.Dispose();
                            _timer = null;
                        }
                    });

                _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tick, null, 0, (int)Interval.TotalMilliseconds);
            }
        }

        //  This is how it must be done in WPF
        //return (new Binding("CurrentTime") { Source = this }).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        //  Xamarin
        return new Binding("CurrentTime") { Source = this };
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try your code exactly so I can't comment on the Xamarin-specific stuff, but getting the IProvideValueTarget our of the serviceProvider was a very helpful piece of advice.  I HATE functions like IServiceProvider.GetService() where you have NO idea what the possible services are but it seems like in this case, it's the only way to get the information on the target object and property.

Comment: I ended up with a slightly different solution, I still used IProvideValueTarget because I needed to know a little bit about the context of my extension, but what I did was create a property in my extension and then ProvideValue() returns a Binding that I created to that property.  I don't think it's documented anywhere, but when I change my property (and fire the PropertyChanged event), XAML is able to pick up on that and copies the new value of my extension's property into the XAML items' property.  Voila!

Comment: Yeah, I got that from the WPF reference source for `Binding`. "You should know enough to go read the source" isn't what I call documentation.

Comment: @BettyCrokker That's nice! Embarrassed to admit I didn't think of implementing INPC on my markup extension itself. That's much better than my version.

Comment: Thanks for posting some real code for those who read this later!  One small change though, I return the Binding itself, not the Binding.ProvideValue() ...

Comment: @BettyCrokker Thanks, I wondered about that: I tried returning the binding, and in WPF that didn't work (and in WPF, `BindingBase.ProvideValue()` returns `BindingExpression`, not `Binding`). I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @BettyCrokker See update -- is that what yours looks like?